How do I add Rigify bones that arent generated yet to it's UI
I made a rig that I intended to generate a rigify rig with but I did not use the metarig preset to make the rig so I had to add all the colors and bone collections manually.
The thing is that when I was organizing the UI before generating the rig, I never had the option to add bone collections to it like tweak, IK, FK, ect. so when I disable the left arm bone collection for instance it will hide ALL bones relating to the left arm and i dont have the option to just disable the tweak or FK bones.
Would I need to remake the whole metarig using the metarig preset that comes with rigify or is there a way to fix it and re-generate the rig
